# How to create an expandable/collapsible list of items with ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have my list of elements, but when I click any of them, they all expand.

Is there a way to make isHidden unique to each element in the list, so only one will expand at a time?

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      <div class="collapsible" (click)="isHidden=!isHidden">
        <div [hidden]="isHidden">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In a perfect world, I'd like any currently expanded elements to collapse when clicking another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you has two approach

1.-Only one expanded each time

You use a variable "indexExpanded" and in loop you equal to index

```
indexExpanded:number=-1

<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
  <div class="collapsible" (click)="indexExpanded=indexExpanded==i?-1:i">
    <div [hidden]="indexExpanded!=i?true:null">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See that is is yet expanded you equal to -1

2.-You can expand one or more items
So you need use so many variables expanded as items you has. In general you use the own "object" item, really a new property "isExpanded"

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="collapsible" (click)="item.isExpanded=!item.isExpanded">
    <div [hidden]="!item.isExpanded?true:null">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: You can use also `*ngIf` or `[style.display]=(condition)?'none':null` better than `[hidden]`

Comment: Great answer, really appreciate the multiple approaches and suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that using the index for the second approach would be a better practice especially when using a typed object that has no property `isExpanded`. Using the index for multiple items should be stored in a dictionary or array.

Comment: @ShayD, yes, you can use an auxiliar array:`arrayExpanded=this.item.map(_=>false)` and use `arrayExpanded[i]=!arrayExpanded[i]` or add a new property to index `this.item.forEach(x=>x.isExpanded=false)`, both options are valid

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer provided, may i know for the second solution, what does it meant by item.isExpanded = !item.isExpanded ?  and what does isExpanded do? And what does the "using own object item" means? Really appreciate it if you would explain to me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in .ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
this.items = this.items.map(item => item.isHidden = true)
}
```

in .html file

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="collapsible" (click)="item.isHidden=!item.isHidden">
   <div [hidden]="item.isHidden">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to avoid editing the data object.

Comment: @godocmat. You can not use "map", your code makes that this.items becomes into an array of true, but you loose the "items". do you want to use `forEach`?

Comment: @Eliseo you are right, but you can use map like this: 
`this.items.map(item => { item.isHidden = true; return item});`

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material - [Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion) is what you need.

The steps:

1. Install Angular Material if you haven't done it before

   - ng add @angular/material
2. Import MatExpansionModule in your module files.

```
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion'; <-- Add this

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatExpansionModule, <-- Add this
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. in HTML file: embedded your *ngFor template by using <mat-expansion-panel> inside <mat-accordion>

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items"
    (opened)="item.panelOpenState = true"
    (closed)="item.panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{item.title}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{item.panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

4. in component.ts file: a sample list items

```
  items : any[] = [
    {title: "title of item 1", content: "content of item 1", panelOpenState: false},
    {title: "title of item 2", content: "content of item 2", panelOpenState: false},
    {title: "title of item 3", content: "content of item 3", panelOpenState: false},
    {title: "title of item 4", content: "content of item 4", panelOpenState: false},
  ];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvyuhq-jqufvv)