# disabled property not working in angular for button

Tags: angular

I have tried both [disabled] or disabled.It is not working as per my condition in typescript.I have around 4 buttons where i need to implement this based on my typescript condition.My requirement is to disable the button based on the typescript condition.I have around 7 conditions with which i need to evaluate.As of now the button gets disabled irrespective of the condition.Please suggest me any other ways to achieve it

```
**HTML**
<button type="button" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled"
              style="background: #79CEA4 !important;color: #FFFFFF !important;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 600;margin-right: 20px"
              class="btn  btn-lg" (click)="finish()">FINISH</button>
**TS**
isButtonDisabled:boolean;
for (var EmployeeList of Employee){
        if ((EmployeeList.EmployeeStatus== 'Active')  {
          this.isButtonDisabled= false;
          return 'circle3';  
        }
        else if((EmployeeList.EmployeeStatus== 'Inactive') {
           this.isButtonDisabled= true;
           return 'circle1';

}
```

Comment: You have an unique variable to "mannage" a serie of buttons. IT's a bit like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263734/how-to-create-an-expandable-collapsible-list-of-items-with-ngfor/67263964#67263964) or use an unique variable "index" or use an array of variables

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular's `ChangeDetectorRef` in your ts file.
It is used to detect changes and reflect into your DOM objects or HTML.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

isButtonDisabled:boolean;

for (var EmployeeList of Employee) {
  if (EmployeeList.EmployeeStatus == "Active") {
    this.isButtonDisabled = false;
    ref.detectChanges();
    return "circle3";
  } else if (EmployeeList.EmployeeStatus == "Inactive") {
    this.isButtonDisabled = true;
    ref.detectChanges();
    return "circle1";
  }
}
```

Comment: Didnt help in my case

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this or maybe tell if your variable is changing or not:

```html
<button 
  type="button"
  [ngClass]="{'disabled': isButtonDisabled}"
  style="background: #79CEA4 !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; 
font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; margin-right: 20px"
  class="btn  btn-lg"
  (click)="finish()"
>
  FINISH
</button>
```

And in your css:

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I tried but its giving similar result .It disables the button for all the cases.

Comment: the problem is most likely in your ts file, not sure what you are doing there. It would be good i you can share it @coder_7

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit different way. You can move away from your for each and set/reset flag for each employee. It's your bottleneck where you need to wait until you finish the foreach loop and apply style change. I prefer to use individual verification function, I have mocked up a simple example below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgFor, NgClass],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  <br/>
  <div *ngFor="let u of users">
    <p>{{u.name}}</p>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled(u)" [ngClass]="isDisabled(u) ? 'circle1' : 'circle2'">Test</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  users = [
    { employeeStatus: 'Active', name: '123' },
    { employeeStatus: 'Else', name: '456' },
  ] as Array<User>;

  constructor() {}

  isDisabled(u: User): boolean {
    // your check conditions
    return u.employeeStatus !== 'Active';
  }
}

interface User {
  employeeStatus: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Live example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-efiqkq?file=src%2Fmain.ts